# Substite Category Slug in a Shortcode

Tags: shortcode, variables

I'm struggling with substituting a variable for a hard-coded value in a shortcode.

I'm using the following shortcode (written by [Ahmed Fouad](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/102371/ahmed-fouad) --thanks Ahmed) at [this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240762/counting-number-of-posts-in-a-category-and-its-sub-categories-and-displaying-res/240763#240763) which counts the # of posts in a category.

```
function category_post_count( $atts ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'category' => null
), $atts );
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $atts['category'], 'category');
return ( isset( $term->count ) ) ? $term->count : 0; 
}
add_shortcode( 'category_post_count', 'category_post_count' );
```

It works great and I get the correct count, *provided* I hard code the name of the category, e.g. "computers" below:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[category_post_count category="computers"]'); ?>`

I want the shortcode to automatically insert the name of the category. So I used the following to grab the category's slug (from [Rachel Baker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/8054/rachel-baker) at [this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131216/how-to-get-parent-category-slug-of-current-post) -- thanks, Rachel):

```
$category = get_the_category(); 
$category_parent_id = $category[0]->category_parent;
if ( $category_parent_id != 0 ) {
  $category_parent = get_term( $category_parent_id, 'category' );
  $css_slug = $category_parent->slug;
} else {
  $css_slug = $category[0]->slug;
}
```

This, too, works great and gets the correct category name ("computers"). But when I insert the $css_slug variable into the shortcode, like this, I get a zero count:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[category_post_count category=$css_slug]'); ?>
```

What am I doing incorrectly with the assignment? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[category_post_count category='.$css_slug.']'); ?>
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do though?  If you're not doing this in actual content pages, you don't need the shortcode.

You could just do it all within the php page.  Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, rudtek. That didn't work, unfortunately. 

I'm trying to display a bulleted list of titles of other posts related to this post's category(s), limited to 10, at the bottom of a single-content.php page. And display nothing if there are no related-category posts.

It seemed pretty simple at first but I'm a Wordpress/PHP 'noob' and I've been all over the map for days. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: what is the error when you put that code in?

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. It does work (been looking at it so long, that I didn't put the quotes around '.$css_slug.' as you had). Thank you, rudtek. Works great.

I like your suggestion of not using a shortcode to get the category count -- but don't know how to write that. Is that pretty simple? (Reason I need the counts is to ignore displaying related-category posts if count <= 1.)

Comment: glad it worked!  mind marking as answered?  It would be a bit of work, but if what you have is working, you're good to go.

Comment: It works like a champ! You're a gem, rudtek. Thank you so, so much. :)

Comment: P.S. Rudtek, could you please point me to what I could have searched for that explains the solution you came up with (the way you used quotes and periods around the var...) Thanks. :)

Comment: you're switching between php and html... concatenation.